# Beginning in Flutter: How do I make 4 buttons fill a SafeArea

Tags: android, flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I've very much a beginner in Dart and Flutter, and my project is to learn while building an app. I've learned the basics with an online class and I have basis in Java.

Now, in my homepage, I'm trying to have 4 buttons take the whole screen. My current layout is to have them all take an equal amount of space and be stacked vertically.
Problem is, I can't find a way to make the RaisedButton fill automatically. I've tried retrieving the height of the screen and dividing that between the buttons but it's not working. Here's how I do it :
First, the homescreen layout:

```
class Homescreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 60;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: [
            PlanningButton(height),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
            BookingButton(height),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
            ModifyButton(height),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0)),
            CancelButton(height),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

As you can see, I pass the height argument to my buttons all built around this model:

```
  Widget PlanningButton(double pixel_y) {
    return RaisedButton(
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(pixel_y / 8.0),
      onPressed: () {}, //goes to the planning screen
      color: Colors.blue[200],
      child: Text("Planning"),
    );
  }
```

Yet, it's never quite right. I don't think it's taking into account the notification bar or the navigation bar.
I suspect there is a workaround that involves wrapping the buttons into a container or using a different kind of widget that have button-like properties but I can't find what suits my needs.

Thanks for any help !

edit: I'm basically trying to do [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HQrf3.jpg)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Before you read this, it's not the best way to do things but it's one I'm using at least for prototyping. You may find using a container with a list and the argument MainAxisAlignment to work better for you.

A lot of comments here might give a solution that works for you but here's mine. I got it to work like I wanted by using `SizedBox`.

First, I recovered the width of the screen, then I created the buttons and put them into SizedBox fitting the screen's width, I put them in a `Column` and I added a few `Container` for the style points.

Result:
[image]

Code :

```
class Homescreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(context) {
    double width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width; //getting screen width
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
          children: [
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)),
            PlanningButton(width),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)),
            BookingButton(width),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)),
            ModifyButton(width),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)),
            CancelButton(width),
            Container(margin: EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 20.0)),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  Widget PlanningButton(double width) {
    return Expanded(
      child: SizedBox(
        width: width - 20,
        child: RaisedButton(
          onPressed: () {},
          color: Colors.blue,
          child: Text(
            "planning",
            textScaleFactor: 4.0,
          ),
        ),
        //fit: BoxFit.cover,
      ),
    );
  }
```

The user can tap anywhere on the colored buttons and it will register. Now I'll add images and transparency to make it look good!

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the variable height logic, and simply wrap your buttons in `Expanded` widgets. This is pretty much what it was built for.

Check it out here: https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/Expanded-class.html

Comment: When I do that, it only expands the button horizontally.
https://imgur.com/a/mxVNMcI

Comment: Oh yes, I didn't realize you didn't have a Column. Glad it works now!

Answer (score 0):

If 4 buttons are the only widgets, you dont need to use `ListView` just use a Column with `mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly`

```
class Sample extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceBetween,
          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.red,
                child: Center(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("button"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.blue,
                child: Center(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("button"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.green,
                child: Center(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("button"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
            Expanded(
              child: Container(
                color: Colors.yellow,
                child: Center(
                  child: RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: () {},
                    child: Text("button"),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Close but not right. [image](https://imgur.com/a/mhWCtr1) I thought I could solve it by getting the width of the screen and doing an 'EdgeInset` but I'd need to substract the default button size and can't find how to retrieve that information.

Comment: so you want even button height but not included the notification bar height?

Comment: Basically yes. I would like the button to take up all of the screen save for the navigation button bar at the bottom and the notification bar at the top. I'm getting close with FittedBox but it's still not that. [There's actually a good example of my objective on the flutter homepage](https://imgur.com/a/iHxKcJO)

Comment: by the way i just checked again it work fine on mine..did you wrap the column in SafeArea()?... If still not, this will get that statusbar/notification height  double statusBarHeight = MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top;
    print("statusBarHeight: $statusBarHeight");....

Comment: I have literally copied and pasted your code and it does what's in the image I've linked earlier. I'm lost as to why it works for you and not me..And this is just being put in a MaterialApp's body. I'll try what you sent it seems like it would work though I'd have to do the same for the navigation button bar at the bottom of android phones.

Comment: Good workaround, but I wanted the whole surface to be a button. I think I found an answer with the SizedBox, I'll post my solution tomorrow, now it's 4am and I'm gonna head to bed. Thanks a lot for your time, I learned a lot.

Answer (score 0):

You could use a `Column` and `Expanded` to do the job. If you want to make your `Column` scrollable, you can wrap it with `SingleChildScrollView`. I used `SizedBox` instead of `Container` to make the spacing because it is way more efficient and is designed for it.

```
class Homescreen extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(context) {
    double height = MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 60;
    return Scaffold(
      body: SafeArea(
        child: Column(
          children: <Widget>[
            Expanded(
              child: PlanningButton(height)
            ),
            SizedBox(height:20),
            Expanded(
              child: BookingButton(height),
            ),
            SizedBox(height:20),
            Expanded(
              child: ModifyButton(height),
            ),
            SizedBox(height:20),
            Expanded(
              child: CancelButton(height),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
```

Comment: Yep, with some tweaking that's basically what I was looking for, thanks a lot!